# Regex in JMeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

Hi I'm trying to get the Id of a design from a web page my regular expression is:

> "http://basic-modele.ini.fr/design/view/(.*?)"

The problem is that the url changes it can be **basic-modele.ini.fr** or any other url I tried with:

> "http://*/design/view/(.*?)"

and with:

> "http://.*./design/view/(.*?)"

but no one of those are working, any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change `(.*?)` to `(.*)`, perhaps?

Comment: (.*?) is working well when the url is there, the problems is that Jmeter does not like when I change **basic-modele.ini.fr** to \* or to .\*. like: "http://.\*./design/view/(.*?)"

Answer (score 0):

solved with: `http:\/\/.*?\/design\/view\/(.*?)`

Comment: In regex synthax, "," means "any character", so you should escape it when you need to match a "." like in ".fr". A more efficent expression for your match can be: "http://[^/]?/design/view/(.?)" . the meaning is: match anything until you find a slash.